# How do I use the group argument for the plot_summs() function from the jtools package?

Tags: r, coefficients

I am plotting my coefficient estimates using the function [`plot_summs()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/jtools/versions/2.1.0/topics/plot_summs) and would like to divide my coefficients into two separate groups.

The function `plot_summs()` has an argument `groups`, however, when I try to use it as explained in the documentation, I do not get any results nor error. Can someone give me an example of how I can use this argument please?

This is the code I currently have:

plot_summs(model.c, scale = TRUE, groups = list(pane_1 = c("AQI_average", "temp_yearly"), pane_2 = c("rain_1h_yearly", "snow_1h_yearly")), coefs = c("AQI Average"= "AQI_average", "Temperature (in Farenheit)" = "temp_yearly","Rain volume in mm" = "rain_1h_yearly", "Snow volume in mm" = "snow_1h_yearly"))

And the image below is what I get as a result. What I would like to get is to have two panes separate panes. One which would include "AQI_average" and "temp_yearly" and the other one that would have "rain_1h_yearly" and "snow_1h_yearly". Event though I use the groups argument, I do not get this.

[Output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYzty.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Can you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: Hi, thank you. I have just uploaded my code and output. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By minimal reproducible example, markus is refering to a piece of code that enables others to exactly reproduce the issue you are refering to on our respective computers, as described in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that they provided.

To me, it seems the problem is that the *groups* function does not seem to work in plot_summs - it seems someone [here](https://github.com/jacob-long/jtools/issues/88) also pointed it out.

If plot_summs is replaced by plot_coef, the groups function work for me. However, the *scale* function does not seem to be available. A workaround might be:

```
r <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data = iris)

y <- plot_summs(r, scale = TRUE) #Plot for scaled version
t <- plot_coefs(r, #Plot for unscaled versions but with facetting
                groups = 
                  list(
                    pane_1 = c("Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length"), 
                    pane_2 = c("Petal.Width"))) + theme_linedraw()

y$data$group <- t$data$group #Add faceting column to data for the plot
t$data <- y$data #Replace the data with the scaled version

t
```

I hope this is what you meant!